# How do I set a datePicker's min and max to only apply when editing?

Tags: swift, datepicker, maxdate, mindate

I have a compact date picker that gets its date from an api. This date can be anywhere in time (no restrictions) I then set that date to the datePicker. All works fine.

I want to allow the user to accurately view the date the compact datepicker is displaying (the date that has come down from the api) then tap on this compact date picker to edit the date. However, I don't want them picking any date from the past. So I set min date to Date() (the current date)

**Issue:**
By doing this, if the date coming from the api is in the past, it will not display that date. It will instead display todays date. (the current date)

**So Question:**
How do I continue to allow the date picker to display a date from the past, but not allow the user to manually change it to a date in the past?

Comment: have a look at this, it will tell you exactly how to do it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepicker

Comment: Thanks, but sorry I didn't specify the language. I am using the UIDatePicker in swift not SwiftUI

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you are asking? The question is not totally understandable.

Comment: Essentially, I need the date picker to have a min and max date when the user is picking a date. (The user should not be able to pick a date in the past.) I also need that same date picker to be able to display a date in the past if it is assigned one programmatically.

Comment: Another way of wording this is, I should be able to programmatically assign a past date to the date picker, and the user should be able to see that past date. But when the user taps on it to change it, they should not be able to pick a new date in the past. The minimum date they should be able to pick is the current date.

Comment: You can change the minimumDate when user wanted to select a date. Use `valueChanged` property for change the minimumDate when user wanted to select a date.

Comment: `func setupDatePicker() {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
}

@objc func onValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
        sender.minimumDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 458742323)
}`

Add target for datePicker's valueChanged property. Update the minimumDate inside this handler.

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't set the minimum date in time to gray it out for the user to not select it. This will also give (and leave) the date picker with a minimum date, which is not good either because then when a past due date comes from the backend, the date picker will not display it due to its minimum date restriction being out of range.